# Arch linux: set keyboard layout to PL

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, keyboard-layout

I'm unsuccessfully trying to force my Arch to set pl layout on X start.

I've googled for solutions, and I found couple of tutorials/tips but none of them works.

My current, keyboard related settings:

```
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8 in /etc/locale.conf
pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8 in /etc/locale.gen
```

I did: `localectl set-x11-keymap pl`
to generate conf for X,

I have created /etc/rc.conf with:

```
#
# /etc/rc.conf - Main Configuration for Arch Linux
#
# See man 5 rc.conf for more details
#

# LOCALIZATION
# ------------
HARDWARECLOCK="UTC"
TIMEZONE="Europe/Warsaw"
KEYMAP="pl"
CONSOLEFONT="lat2-16"
CONSOLEMAP="8859-2"
LOCALE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
DAEMON_LOCALE="yes"
USECOLOR="yes"
```

with no success.

**EDIT:**

Context of important files:

/etc/vconsole.conf:

```
KEYMAP=pl
FONT=lat2-16
FONT_MAP=8859-2
```

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf:

```
# Read and parsed by systemd-localed. It's probably wise not to edit this file
# manually too freely.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "pl"
EndSection
```

**EDIT2:**

output of `localectl` (before `setxkbmap pl`):

```
System Locale: LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
VC Keymap: pl
X11 Layout: pl
```

after `setxkbmap pl` is the same

Comment: Eh? Arch hasn't used an `/etc/rc.conf` for *years*... Use [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keymap)!

Comment: rc.conf was one of the options I found in google. I tried everything. Wiki says about using `localectl` (which I did). My `/etc/vconsole.conf` looks like this:

    `KEYMAP=pl
    FONT=lat2-16
    FONT_MAP=8859-2`

Comment: Please edit the output of `localectl` into your question.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: What Desktop Environment are you using?

Comment: KDE4 (exact version: 4.14.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I've found what was wrong. I didn't have polish language enabled in KDE's control panel.

systemsettings -> input devices -> keyboards -> layouts

Answer (score 2):

I've set my keyboard layout by editing `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf`.

If it doesn't exist go ahead and create it. Put this inside:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbLayout" "pl"
EndSection
```

Save and restart X.

For more information see the section titled **Using X configuration files** [on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Setting_keyboard_layout).

Comment: This is exactly what `localectl set-x11-keymap pl` has generated for me (mentioned in my question). I've tried a little bit different variants also without any success

Comment: To clarify, when you say it isn't working do you mean you aren't able to type Polish characters when pressing alt? (Right alt on my system.)

Comment: 0x0049: exactly. alt+l should give me "ł" but it doesn't. I get "l". Only `setxkbmap pl` helps

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer, otherwise I would do this there, but  like jasonwryan asked can you add the output of `localectl` to your question? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `setxkbmap pl` to your starting scripts (e.g .bashrc)

Comment: That's the only solution I think, but I don't find it "right" way. Also it will cause errors when I login to TTY (as this command requires X)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the "Bash script that changes the language in Arch Linux to Polish" written by me, to be found at
https://github.com/Curar/archlinuxpl.

Run it as follows:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Curar/archlinuxpl/main/archlinuxpl.sh)"
```

I tried to write everything that the script does in the README.md file on github.com . The script changes the language of Arch Linux also at the installation level. It can also be used on a running system (ArchLinux).

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what your script does exactly. That way, even if your script goes offline over time, we'll still be able to work it out :-)